# How can I extract date information in YYYYMMDD format from a file name?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and  have  a string in the format `XXXX_XXX_YYYYMMDD.txt`.

How can I extract `YYYYMMDD` part in another string?

Below is what I tried

```
my $filename = "XXXX_XXX_YYYYMMDD.txt";
my $datepart = split($filename ,'.');
print "$datepart";
```

Comment: What have you tried? Looked at regular expressions (e.g. `m//`)? `split`? Anything else?

Comment: Yes, simply `split` the string.  Take a look at `perldoc -f split`.

Comment: May I know the reasons for down voting me ?

Comment: Why didn't it work?  Stack Overflow is not a "gimmeh teh codez!!!!1" site.  If you want your question to be well-received, you'll have to provide some evidence that you've actually tried something and have put some thought into what you're asking about.

Comment: @Sinan and jack Maney,do not mindlessly downvote. We are all here to help each other.

Comment: @SachinChourasiya - Oh, my downvote, along with my vote to close the question, was anything but mindless.  Please do not be so condescending and arrogant to presume that those who disagree with you do so mindlessly.

Comment: @SachinChourasiya - `split($filename ,'.')` is your problem.  Please look at `perldoc -f split` for the syntax of the `split` function.

Comment: @SachinChourasiya It is a good thing the site is about questions and not posters because you are being way too much of a jerk with calling us mindless. FWIW, I withdrew my downvote after you posted a snippet of code. But, I agree with Jack Maney's response to your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be with substr()

```
my $txt = "abcd_efg_12340322.txt";
print substr($txt, 9, 8);
```

The 9 means to start at the 10th character of the string (counting from 0), and the 8 is the number of chars you need to capture.

Comment: +1, this is probably the simplest answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
 my ($datepart) = ( $filename =~ /([0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2})[.]txt\z/ );
```

`my ($datepart)` creates list context. A regular expression match in list context returns capture groups. The part `/(...)/` is a capture group. Inside, you are matching year (4 digits), month (2 digits), and day (2 digits) followed by the `.txt` extension at the end of the string.

I did it this way so that it is easy to change to:

```
 my ($year, $month, $day) = ( 
      $filename =~ /([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2})[.]txt\z/x
 );
```

if you decide you need the the components separately. If all you want is the `YYYYMMDD`,

```
 my ($datepart) = ( $filename =~ /([0-9]{8})[.]txt\z/ );
```

would also have worked.

See also [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

The problem with using `split '.'` is simple: The first argument to `split` is a pattern. In a pattern `.` is special: It means "match any character". If you had split using `split /[.]/`, you would have put `.` in a character class removing the special meaning, and treating it as a character that matches itself. I prefer that to `split /\./` or `split`qr{.}` for aesthetic reasons.

As @TLP shows, it is possible to use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to get the correct part in this example, but it is better to use `m//` to ensure you are matching only what you want to match.

Comment: Thanks Sinan and Appreciate your nice explanation. I am upvoting you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regular expression that does the trick:

```
/.{4}_.{3}_(.{8})/;
```

And here's it in action:

```
"abcd_efg_12340322.txt" =~ /.{4}_.{3}_(.{8})/; 
print $1;
```

The parentheses capture the string and put it in $1.

Note:  regexes can get nasty (in any language) and this regex could easily go wrong, but if you want to do something quick 'n dirty it might be all right.

There's lots of info out there on perl regexes:  [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: @SachinCHourasiya -- I already tested it and it worked fine on my computer.  What I'm worried about is edge cases -- what if the day or month only has one digit (maybe that's not possible?)?  If you're not worried about running into edge cases, then it should be fine.

Comment: You are completely removing the advantage of using regular expressions by matching any characters that happen to be in the string. Your pattern will also match: `"Hey I know_you_did not want this"`.

Comment: @Sinan -- you are definitely right that it will match lots of things, but that's what the question asked for.  And in my defense, I did say that it "could easily go wrong".  But it seemed to me that the OP might be looking for a quick 'n dirty.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, There are two primary uses for regex matching: validation and data extraction. Your example file name does NOT match the OP's pattern, so it doesn't matter that Matt's pattern matches it. The OP asked for data extraction, not data validation.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple field manipulation with [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

```
$date = (split /[_.]/, $filename)[2];
```

You split the string on underscore and period, and grab the third field with a subscript.